# Procmail copies message instead of moving it

Tags: procmail

What I'm using below works, but a test email lands in both the inbox and the target folder (Stuff). Is there a way to avoid duplicate imap messages?

```
VERBOSE=on
PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
MAILDIR=$HOME/boxes/domain.com/fred^/.imap/
LOGFILE=$HOME/proclog
SHELL=/bin/sh

:0:
* ^Subject:.*test
Stuff
```

The log result:

```
procmail: Assigning "SHELL=/bin/sh"
procmail: Match on "^Subject:.*test"
procmail: Locking "Stuff.lock"
procmail: Assigning "LASTFOLDER=Stuff"
procmail: Opening "Stuff"
procmail: Acquiring kernel-lock
procmail: Unlocking "Stuff.lock"
procmail: Notified comsat: "username@number:/usr/home/username/boxes/domian.com/fred^/.imap//Stuff"
From person@email.com Sat Jan 24 00:04:42 2015
Subject: test
Folder: Stuff                                  2213
```

Update:
Assuming the message is duplicated when it finds a match, here's how I was attempting to sort, then detect and eliminate the duplicate:

```
VERBOSE=yes
LOGABSTRACT=all
PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
LOGFILE=$HOME/proclog
SHELL=/bin/sh

MAILDIR=$HOME/boxes/mydomain.com/
INBOX=$HOME/boxes/mydomain.com/fred
STUFF=$HOME/boxes/mydomain.com/fred^/.imap/Stuff

:0
* ^Subject:.*test
${STUFF}

:0 Whc: msgid.lock
| formail -D 4096 $MAILDIR/msgid.cache

:0 a:
dev/null
```

I've also seen this example:

```
:0 Wh:dup
| formail -D 4096 $MAILDIR/msgid.cache
```

Comment: procmail's invoked by a host provider's filter recipe - all mail for mailbox "fred" through procmail located at /usr/local/bin/procmail. This is where my experience hits the wall, but it appears my host uses Postfix under Dovecot.

Comment: For some reason it's creating a copy with the same message ID. Detecting duplicates might work using ':0 Whc: msgid.lock
| formail -D 4096 msgid.cache' but after dozens of attempts I can't compose a recipe to successfully sort by subject, then weed out the duplicate. I've also seen 'Wh:dup' but which is more appropriate?

Comment: You need to remove duplicates first, then deliver what's left.

Comment: Tx - It's still a mystery to me where this copy is coming from, particularly if it's not being created inadvertently by the filtering in the first example. Wouldn't it make sense to check for duplicates post sorting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69645/discussion-between-bobzilla-and-tripleee).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for all your thoughtful input. Your absolutely right, not related to procmail, and eluded Pair Networks support. BTW, no other recipes in use.

A major stroke of luck: found an ancient post from an extremely helpful Pair Networks user explaining how to write a recipe without letting qmail interfere.

http://ziggr.com/pairmail/

> EXITCODE=99 tells qmail that we are going to take care of delivering each message, and that qmail does not need to deliver it to the
>   mailbox. If we did not do this, qmail would see the default return
>   code 0 (OK) and interpret that as "the filter program said the email
>   was acceptable, so now I should deliver it." This results in duplicate
>   copies of all mail landing in your mailbox, as well as filtered
>   spam/ham copies landing in spam/ham mailboxes.

Included on that page is a diagram showing how qmail handles mail, and a recipe for restoring spamassassin filtering. My own filtering works with no duplicate landing in INBOX, and waiting to find out if spam filtering works ok.

```
LOGFILE=$HOME/proclog
VERBOSE=YES 

# prevent qmail (the program that is calling procmail 
# as a filter) from delivering the original mail.
EXITCODE=99 

MAILDIR=$HOME/boxes/domain.com
INBOX=$MAILDIR/fred
GREY=$MAILDIR/fred^/.imap/grey
JUNK=$MAILDIR/fred^/.imap/Junk
TEST=$MAILDIR/fred^/.imap/Test 


# Spam level 5.0 or greater 
:0
* ^X-Spam-Level: \*\*\*\*\* 
${JUNK}

# Spam level 2.0-4.9: hold in grey area 
:0
* ^X-Spam-Level: \*\* 
${GREY} 

:0:
* ^Subject:.*test
${TEST}

# Spam level < 2.0: it's probably real email, deliver as normal 
:0:
${INBOX}
```

Comment: See also now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28204990/procmail-recipe-causes-wrong-timestamp

Comment: Qmail, huh?  Who woulda thunk.  You should probably accept this answer.

Comment: Yeah, just sayin' it makes sense to include links between these questions (and/or maybe remove your other question from the comment).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems unrelated to Procmail.  If the duplicates were processed by Procmail (and you are showing us all your recipes), they would be delivered to the same mailbox `Stuff` as the messages you are processing, and not into your inbox.  You'll need to examine your provider's Postfix configuration, or simply bring up this problem with their support.

With that out of the way, there are a couple of clarifications that can be made to your Procmail processing.  The duplicate detection makes no sense to perform after you have delivered a message: when a message is delivered, Procmail is done, and the following recipes are never executed.

The recipe you have is slightly erroneous in that you have misspelled `/dev/null` but also hugely inefficient in that you are copying a message only to throw it away.  The standard recipe for discarding duplicates is simply

```
:0Wh:msgid.lock
| formail -D 8192 msgid.cache
```

But above all, this needs to go *before* any delivering recipe.  This one, effectively, delivers to bit heaven if the message is a duplicate of a message we have seen before; and so, Procmail stops processing then and there.  (The "delivery" happens because the message is passed to `formail` for delivery, which of course doesn't deliver it anywhere.  If it's not a duplicate, `formail` -- in this particular mode, with the `-D` option -- signals an error, which causes Procmail to catch the error and resume with the next recipe, hoping that will succeed instead.)

It doesn't really matter what you call the lock file, but `msgid.lock` is pretty standard.  The main thing is that two instances of Procmail need to use the same lock file, so you could call it Shirley and get away with it -- as long as you don't change it, it can be anything (but Shirley is a bad choice because you will forget what it means and call your ISP's support and hysterically claim that some Shirley seems to have hacked your box).

The recipe with a `c` flag is incompletely transcribed from the [`procmailex(5)`](http://man.he.net/man5/procmailex) manual page -- it's an example of how to store suspected duplicates in a separate mailbox instead of throwing them away, just in case.

<sub>I know, don't call me Shirley.</sub>