# procmail recipe causes wrong timestamp

Tags: procmail

This otherwise working recipe causes mail clients to misinterpret the "received" time as 5hrs fast. This is the only recipe in use. When comparing date/time written into both headers, there's essentially no differences. What's a good way to address? Can a recipe compensate?

```
LOGFILE=$HOME/proclog
VERBOSE=YES 

# prevent qmail (the program that is calling procmail 
# as a filter) from delivering the original mail.

EXITCODE=99 

MAILDIR=$HOME/boxes/mydomain.com
INBOX=$MAILDIR/bob
GREY=$MAILDIR/bob^/.imap/grey
JUNK=$MAILDIR/bob^/.imap/Junk
TEST=$MAILDIR/bob^/.imap/Test 

:0
* ^Subject:.*test
${TEST}

# Spam level < 2.0: it's probably real email, deliver as normal 
:0
${INBOX}
```

Below is the header of an email that was sent at 4:05pm, but shows being received at 9:05pm on a desktop email client, and iOS.

```
Return-Path: <from_email@domain.com>
Delivered-To: username-domain:com-bob@domain.com
X-Envelope-To: bob@domain.com
Received: (qmail 16283 invoked from network); 29 Jan 2015 00:05:59 -0000
Received: from mailwash46.pair.com (IP ADDRESS)
  by tanha.pair.com with SMTP; 29 Jan 2015 00:05:59 -0000
Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by mailwash46.pair.com (Postfix) with SMTP id 31958EBC17
    for <bob@domain.com>; Wed, 28 Jan 2015 19:05:59 -0500 (EST)
Received: from tanha.pair.com (tanha.pair.com [IP ADDRESS])
    by mailwash46.pair.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 0E9EBEBFB5
    for <bob@domain.com>; Wed, 28 Jan 2015 19:05:59 -0500 (EST)
Received: from [192.168.1.230] (c-IP ADDRESS.hsd1.wa.comcast.net [IP ADDRESS])
    by tanha.pair.com (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id BE211F1D10
    for <bob@domain.com>; Wed, 28 Jan 2015 19:05:58 -0500 (EST)
User-Agent: Microsoft-Entourage/12.20.0.xxxx
Date: Wed, 28 Jan 2015 16:05:57 -0800
Subject: 405pm test
From: "Robert" <from_email@domain.com>
To: "bob@domain.com" <bob@domain.com>
Message-ID: <D0EEB965.49C7D%from_email@domain.com>
Thread-Topic: 405pm test
Thread-Index: AdA7V1sU8z5udBOZSUyJx4az1tpIXA==
Mime-version: 1.0
Content-type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="B_3505305958_xxxxxx"
```

And an email that shows correct times (essentially the same):

```
Return-Path: <from_email@domain.com>
Delivered-To: username-domain:com-bob@domain.com
X-Envelope-To: bob@domain.com
Received: (qmail 22574 invoked from network); 30 Jan 2015 02:35:23 -0000
Received: from mailwash46.pair.com (IP ADDRESS)
  by tanha.pair.com with SMTP; 30 Jan 2015 02:35:23 -0000
Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by mailwash46.pair.com (Postfix) with SMTP id 4CF3BEBF9D
    for <bob@domain.com>; Thu, 29 Jan 2015 21:35:23 -0500 (EST)
Received: from tanha.pair.com (tanha.pair.com [IP ADDRESS])
    by mailwash46.pair.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 4C278EBF97
    for <bob@domain.com>; Thu, 29 Jan 2015 21:35:23 -0500 (EST)
Received: from [192.168.1.230] (c-IP ADDRESS.hsd1.wa.comcast.net [IP ADDRESS])
    by tanha.pair.com (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 55E98F1BF8
    for <bob@domain.com>; Thu, 29 Jan 2015 21:35:21 -0500 (EST)
User-Agent: Microsoft-Entourage/12.20.0.xxxxxxxx
Date: Thu, 29 Jan 2015 18:35:16 -0800
Subject: test
From: "Robert." <from_email@domain.com>
To: "bob@domain.com" <bob@domain.com>
Message-ID: <D0F02DE4.49D82%from_email@domain.com>
Thread-Topic: test
Thread-Index: AdA8NWF58VbsQ1XhgkuMBHgxsaYksg==
Mime-version: 1.0
Content-type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="B_3505401322_xxxxxxxx"
```

Comment: Mail clients should not be interpreting the `Received:` headers in any way.  Could you show an example of what it looks like and how you would like it to look?  My suspicion is that this is simply UTC versus local and not at all wrong.

Comment: My mail client has a sent and received column. The send column shows the correct time. On ios (Mail) it shows only the +5hr time. I should note that (as I understand it) without EXITCODE=99 invoked, the system delivers the original email (via qmail I think), then delivers the procmail filtered version of the same email to wherever it's been told to go. It's the 2nd filtered email that shows the time discrepancy.

Comment: Sounds like it's not the `Received:` headers then, but either way, please include the headers of an example message in your question and indicate which part is wrong.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure which part of the header is responsible for showing time in the received column (accounting for PST). Side note: Oddly, the system produced two emails of the uppermost email (405pm test) when EXITCODE=99 wasn't invoked, one showing the correct time, the other, 5hrs fast. Both headers of those emails were completely identical.

Comment: ... It's not like the IP address of `tanha.pair.com` is a well-kept secret.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to look for a proper specification for "received date" but could not find any.  However, I stumbled across https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=402594 which between the lines indicates that mail clients are in fact parsing the `Received:` headers for this information.  Now, the question remains, which `Received:` header do they look at, and what's wrong with this header in your problematic case?  There is nothing there which specifically translates to 21:05 (an exact copy of the timestamp displayed by your IMAP client(s) would be handy for diagnostics) so this is entirely speculative -- but if you can come up with better speculations, at least I can show you how to solve the technical question of how to replace something in the headers.

I am assuming we should look at the topmost `Received:` header and simply normalize its time zone to whatever you expect to see (which seems to be -0800 PST).

```
TZ="America/Los_Angeles"
:0fhW
* ^Received:[   ]*from[         ]*.*($[         ].*)*; \
        ()\/(Mon|T(ue|hu)|Wed|Fri|S(at|un)), \
        [0-3 ][0-9] (A(pr|ug)|Dec|Feb|J(an|u[nl])|Ma[ry]|Oct|Sep) \
        20[1-9][0-9] [0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-6][0-9] [-+][01][0-9][0134][05] \
        \([A-Z]+T\)
| d=`date -R -d "$MATCH"`; sed "s/$MATCH/$d/"
```

Now, this is obviously rather brittle, but at least shows you in rough terms how this could be done.  For a more portable and robust approach, I would perhaps work this into an external script (Python, Perl, what have you) instead of coding it in Procmail and shell script.  (You could still run it from Procmail, of course -- I would simply make a script which can be run on all your incoming email, which would only modify the ones which need to be changed.)

This extracts the date stamp out of the first matching header (maybe you should tweak it to only match on -0500 time zones in particular?) and replaces any match on that specific date string with a new one, produced by calling `date -R -d` with the captured date as the argument, which converts it to whatever time zone this is running in (which we set with the `TZ` variable assignment -- this is tricky voodoo, I can never remember the correct syntax for numeric time zones so I simply looked up a common name for -0800).

The datestamp regex is ad hoc, but I seem to have remembered at least space vs zero padding for single-digit days of the month as well as leap seconds and time zones which are not on even hours from UTC.  I'm sure there are still some details that I am missing, or just silly thinkos.

There's an even more-topmost `(qmail xxx invoked from network)` header which I am ignoring -- it has the time stamp in a different, non-RFC822 format, so I'm guessing this is ignored by your IMAP client, too.

The wacky empty parentheses before the `\/` regex capturing token is because Procmail *is* wacky when it comes to a backslash at the start of a line.

Comment: Another speculation would be that the client somehow queries the IMAP server for a time stamp which is somehow maintained in its internal database. Maybe figure out which IMAP server this is, and whether Qmail somehow does something special when delivering into its message store.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much. This is getting a bit beyond me I admit. Msg went undelivered. Here's the log, sorry this isn't more readable: procmail: Executing " d=`date -R -d "$MATCH"`; sed "s/$MATCH/$d/""
date: illegal option -- R
usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[[[cc]yy]mm]dd]HH]MM[.ss]] [+format]
d=: Command not found.
d: Undefined variable.
procmail: Non-zero exitcode (1) from " d=`date -R -d "$MATCH"`; sed "s/$MATCH/$d/""
procmail: Rescue of unfiltered data succeeded

Comment: GNU `date` has an `-R` option which produces RFC822 date format, but apparently you don't have that (or your GNU `coreutils` is really old).  One more point for writing this in a portable scripting language.

Comment: But again, the fact that you got different results for two messages with identical headers is a strong hint that this is altogether unrelated to your Procmail recipes.  I'm actually tempted to nominate this for migration to https://serverfault.com/ because your problem seems to be unrelated to programming in general and Procmail scripting in particular. Or maybe, accept this answer and ask again on SF, with more and different details.

Comment: You can get an RFC 822 date with `date +'%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z (%Z)'` where the `(%Z)` is optional (it's just a comment as per RFC822), provided your `date` has all of these format strings.  (`%z` in partcular might be missing, in which case, again, try a scripting language with a proper date library.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting a second answer to address the IMAP server-side speculation from a Procmail perspective.

If Qmail does something special when delivering to your inbox, you need to do the same thing from your Procmail recipes.  So where you have

```
:0
$INBOX
```

you should instead have

```
:0
| whatever it is that qmail is doing to deliver into "$INBOX"
```

I'm sorry I cannot be more specific about what should be in the pipeline.  Depending on the IMAP server, you can look up popular delivery actions for [Dovecot](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/procmail), Courier (which however seems to prefer `maildrop` over `procmail`), [Cyrus](https://serverfault.com/questions/317206/procmail-deliver-to-cyrus-imap), etc; or simply look at your ISP's Qmail configuration to see what it's doing.

Comment: Thanks so much. I will continue to chip away at this.